# Calling to a database in Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-3.x

I have a database with data sets like below how do call the remaining column data from a row I call using the first value.

For example how can I call `'12345'` and be returned `'1a2b3c' 'Anna' '1'`.

```
"12345" "1a2b3c"    "Anna"  "1"

"45678" "123abc"    "Cathy" "2"

"54321" "zaybxc"    "Alan"  "3"
```

I Googled around but couldn't find the syntax to make it work my solutions keep returning empty.

```
def get_account_balances(db, number):
    totals = []

    con =  sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur = con.cursor()    

    cur.execute('SELECT Savings, Chequing FROM Accounts')
    cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: you are checking if Number == number... That will never happen.. assuming you have a variable `number` try `Number =='+number`

Comment: the number was a parameter from the function call...sorry about that.

Comment: *keep returning empty:* Did you write `return` in your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your new version, you never used that `number` variable.

In your old version:

```
WHERE Number == number
```

^ SQL will test that your `number` row is equals `Number` row or not. So your row called number and you want to check if it's equals your `number` variable or not, try:

```
cur.execute('SELECT Savings, Chequing FROM Accounts WHERE Number == (?)', [number])
```

---

Your function doesn't return anything because you didn't write `return` in your function, try:

```
def get_account_balances(db, number):
    totals = []

    con =  sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur = con.cursor()    

    cur.execute('SELECT Savings, Chequing FROM Accounts WHERE Number == (?)',
                [number])

    return cur.fetchone()
```

Comment: or maybe something like `cur.execute('SELECT Savings, Chequing FROM Accounts where number=='+number)` would work

Comment: @Busturdust: Yeah, but use `(?)` can avoid sql injection, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613037/is-this-python-code-vulnerable-to-sql-injection-sqlite3 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528511/python-sqlite3-sql-injection-vulnerable-code.