# Placing a python an input variable with a psycopg2 update command to a specific column

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am a beginner with Flask, Psycopg2, and Python and I have this little problem, I have created an input() variable that reads users' answer and I want that answer to be put into my databases tables specific column.

```
print('Are the eyes Open or Closed?: ')
estate1 = input()

def update_Eyes(self):
update_command = ("UPDATE Eyes SET cstate=%s Where id=1", (estate1,))
self.cursor.execute(update_command)
print("Eye table update successful ")

database_connection = DatabaseConnection()
database_connection.update_Eyes()
```

If I try to add any values myself, it works just fine but I can't seem to find a solution to adding a variable.

The error code looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/AJ/Desktop/Data Processing/Flask/first.py", line 136, in <module>
database_connection.update_Eyes()  # Updates Table Eyes
File "C:/Users/AJ/Desktop/Data Processing/Flask/first.py", line 98, in update_Eyes
self.cursor.execute(update_command)
TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're compiling your command into `update_command` you are storing this as a Tuple:

```py
estate1 = 'test'
update_command = ("UPDATE Eyes SET cstate=%s Where id=1", (estate1,))
print(type(update_command))

<type 'tuple'>
```

The error is saying that its expecting a String. So, change `update_command` to:

```py
update_command = "UPDATE Eyes SET cstate = '{0}' Where id=1".format(estate1)
```

After the change, you'll see something like this:

```py
update_command = "UPDATE Eyes SET cstate = '{0}' Where id=1".format(estate1)
print(type(update_command))
<type 'str'>
```

If you're worried about SQL Injection, [you can visit this explanation of how to handle user input correctly.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29528944/11588748)

Comment: @Abelisto, Sure mate, have updated the answer with a link to escaping characters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

That is a perfect solution

```
update_command = "UPDATE Eyes SET cstate = '{0}' Where id=1".format(estate1)
```

I just had to add extra quotation marks around '{0}' to make it read strings and it works perfectly fine. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: What if the `estate1` value contains the quotation character? `"foo '{0}'".format("a'b")` Or, moreover, somebody enters something like `a' ; drop table Eyes; commit;`? (It is called "SQL injection", search for this term)

Comment: This user input should be a sensor in an autonomous vehicle, no data regarding the customer would be placed there. It is only to prevent the driver from falling asleep or just monitoring. but that is a good point I will definitely look into that! :)

Comment: In any case `self.cursor.execute("UPDATE Eyes SET cstate=%s Where id=1", (estate1,))` is simpler and safer. Good luck!