# User input SQL Lite and Python and store

Tags: python, sqlite, store

I need help I want the tax column to be calculated from the income column
Also I need the information to be stored in the database from the user input.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('tax1.db')
c = conn.cursor()
#c.execute("""CREATE TABLE tax (
          #First text,
          #Last text,
          #Income real,
          #Tax real
          #)""")
```

#c.execute("INSERT INTO tax VALUES('Henry', 'Bass', 80000, 20000)")

```
for i in range(1):
         First = input("Please enter first name:")
         Last = input("Please enter last name:")
         Income = input("Please enter annual income:")
         conn.execute("INSERT INTO tax VALUES ('{}", "{}", 
         {})).format(First,Last,Income))

        c.execute("SELECT * FROM tax WHERE Last='Bass'")
        print(c.fetchall())
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: So what are you having problems with from this code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the tax calculated from the income I would suggest something like a lookup table:

```py
tax_ratios = {"low_income": 0.1, "medium_income": 0.2, "big_income": 0.3, "huge_income": 0.45}
```

Then after the user has made his inputs you could check with if-statements to which catogorie he belongs:

```py
if Income > 250000:
    tax_ratio = tax_ratios["huge_income"]
if Income < 250000 and Income > 10000:
    tax_ratio = tax_ratios["big_income"]
if Income < 10000 and Income > 70000:
    tax_ratio = tax_ratios["medium_income"]
if Income < 70000:
    tax_ratio = tax_ratios["low_income"]
```

Then you can multiply the income with the tax ratio and store it in the database:

```py
tax_absolute = tax_ratio*Income
conn.execute("INSERT INTO tax VALUES ('{}", "{}", 
         {}, {})).format(First,Last,Income, tax_absolute))
```

Of course this easy lookup table is not complex enough to deal with complicated tax systems but it might be a good start.

If I may add something regarding the database safety:
With formatting the SQL-Query as a string it is easy for an attacker to perform what is called SQL-Injection. You find a good explanation[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528511/python-sqlite3-sql-injection-vulnerable-code).

Comment: Thank you so much- I'm new to programming this isn't going to go live, I just couldn't figure out how to perform the following. I thought if I had someone explain it I could work backwards this has really helped.

Comment: No worries I would appreciate it if you could mark my answer as accepted :)